# better way to automate a multiple searchbox using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

i have to automate search option in below url :

https://qa.roofandfloor.com/

currently,I am selecting single dropdown one by one and searching properties and automating it,just wondering if there is more better/effective way to automate it.

can someone help me on this design pattern.

i know its mostly a theoretical issue,but i need a better way to design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand core of your application, how it populates data in drop down, how it searches the query. That'd help you to prepare test properly.

For an instance if you select property type as `plot` then it disables the bedrooms drop-down without knowing about city you have selected.So you do not need to automate this scenario for all available cities you can just randomly select any city and verify whether bedrooms drop-down gets disabled or not for plot property.

Keep this in mind that that you do not need to automate all possible cases which do not make any sense. Follow [Test Pyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Try to prepare test cases with less test data combination but with better coverage in terms of front-end possibilities.

In terms of automation framework I'd recommend to use Page Object Model as you will always see search results in same way with different text. Don't verify the data which get returned after search as I do not see any relation between your search query and the data which get displayed after search. You should just verify whether all the text,symbols,buttons get displayed or not. You should check whether buttons are functional or not.

Search result should be verified by some other automated test like API automated test or unit tests. Which will confirm that date which gets displayed there are relevant to search query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with hybrid framework + dataprovider.Please see https://automationtestingsimplified.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/hybrid-testing-data-keyword-driven-using-selenium/.